# insert variables into an editor and visualize the actual result

Tags: mustache, froala

I'm using froala, as a text editor, I'm adding variables from a pull-down menu, all right up there, now I want to preview the final format but with the value of each cariable used

```
$.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('variables', { NAME: 'cog' });
    $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('variables', {
      title: 'Advanced options',
      type: 'dropdown',
      focus: false,
      undo: false,
      refreshAfterCallback: true,
      options: _self.employeeModel,
      callback: function (cmd, val) {
        console.log(val);
        this.html.insert('{{' + val + '}}');

      },
      // Callback on refresh.
      refresh: function ($btn) {
        console.log('do refresh');
      },
      // Callback on dropdown show.
      refreshOnShow: function ($btn, $dropdown) {
        console.log('do refresh when show');
      }
    });
```

it looks good in the editor: " my name {{name}} lives in {{address}}"

to visualize I've tried with

but sige showing `{{name}}` how can I replace by its content the one that is in an object `employee`

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Mustache.render()` on the editor output so that you get the variables rendered.